# how to case insentive contain search with lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search, lodash

I have a valid json file (i put only a limited part of that). i want to search incasesensitive and look as contain (suppose there is a record of Red Carpet in json file , if user search "red" it will show the matches's video_url (video_url of "Red Carpet). I have a limitation that i can't use ES6 because of hardware. please show how do i need to convert following json file to javascript object and use jquery or javascript to make a contain incasesensitive search. I can add lodash or any other javascript library to my project for this purpose.

```
[{
        "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Zane_Ziadi_HQ.mp4",
        "title": "Zane Ziadi"
    },
    {
        "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/DarBastAzadiHQ.mp4",
        "title": "Darbast Azadi"
    },
    {
        "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Cheghadr_Vaght_Dari_HQ.mp4",
        "title": "Cheghadr Vaght Dari"
    },
    {
        "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Mashaal_HQ.mp4",
        "title": "Mashaal"
    },
    {
        "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Red_Carpet_HQ.mp4",
        "title": "Red Carpet"
    }
]
```

following code doesn't work :

```
  document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function() {

 var name = document.getElementById('input').value.toLowerCase();
    var result = _.find(movies, {'title': name});
    if (!result){
       console.log('Nothing found');
    }else{
         console.log('Go to ' + result.video_url);

    }
    });
```

**Edit2: update2**

fixed and solved by Akrion comment, thanks so much to him

**Edit3: update3**

it seemed by Akrion answer, when search a for character "a" it would not return all title which has A as character , please modify and correct the code i try to run ES5 part answer and it only return zane ziadi the first item but not "Cheghadr Vaght Dari"

**Edit4: update4**
as Akrion suggested in his comment i can use filter instead of find to match all searches. i mark his answer for this thread forever

Comment: @Akrion please see this related topic with different subject thanks so much : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312728/how-convert-lodash-object-to-the-jquerys-listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are asking `lodash` to compare the exact contents of `title` and more importantly compare it while being case sensitive, since `{title: name}` triggers property match in lodash which simply compares the contents of title with the contents of the variable.

You can create a search function via `lodash` methods and no ES6 like this:

```js
const data = [{ "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Zane_Ziadi_HQ.mp4", "title": "Zane Ziadi" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/DarBastAzadiHQ.mp4", "title": "Darbast Azadi" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Cheghadr_Vaght_Dari_HQ.mp4", "title": "Cheghadr Vaght Dari" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Mashaal_HQ.mp4", "title": "Mashaal" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Red_Carpet_HQ.mp4", "title": "Red Carpet" } ]

const search = function(data, term) {
  return _.find(data, function(x) { 
    return _.includes(_.toLower(x.title), _.toLower(term))}) 
  }

console.log(search(data, 'azadi'))
console.log(search(data, 'Red'))
console.log(search(data, 'zan'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using `find`, `includes` and `toLower` [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#) methods.

Your code then would look like:

```
function search(data, term) {
  return _.find(data, function(x) { 
    return _.includes(_.toLower(x.title), _.toLower(term))}) 
}

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var name = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var result = search(movies, name);  // <-- change to use the new search fn
  if (result) {
    console.log('Nothing found');
  } else {
    console.log('Go to ' + result.video_url);
  }
});
```

With **ES5** you can also do this via:

```js
const data = [{ "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Zane_Ziadi_HQ.mp4", "title": "Zane Ziadi" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/DarBastAzadiHQ.mp4", "title": "Darbast Azadi" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Cheghadr_Vaght_Dari_HQ.mp4", "title": "Cheghadr Vaght Dari" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Mashaal_HQ.mp4", "title": "Mashaal" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Red_Carpet_HQ.mp4", "title": "Red Carpet" } ]

const search = function(data, term) {
  return data.find(function(x) {
    return x.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) >= 0 })
} 

console.log(search(data, 'azadi'))
console.log(search(data, 'Red'))
console.log(search(data, 'zan'))
```

With **ES6** this would simply be:

```js
const data = [{ "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Zane_Ziadi_HQ.mp4", "title": "Zane Ziadi" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/DarBastAzadiHQ.mp4", "title": "Darbast Azadi" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Cheghadr_Vaght_Dari_HQ.mp4", "title": "Cheghadr Vaght Dari" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Mashaal_HQ.mp4", "title": "Mashaal" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Red_Carpet_HQ.mp4", "title": "Red Carpet" } ]

const search = (data, term) => 
  data.find(({title}) => title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()))

console.log(search(data, 'azadi'))
console.log(search(data, 'Red'))
console.log(search(data, 'zan'))
```

Please note that this is not a super **performant** approach and if you are going to search hundreds/thousands of documents this way it will not perform well. You would need to look into other ways (Binary search etc) to solve this.

Comment: Interesting they all work in the browser. What is the error for the lodash one? First suggestion.

Comment: So you are telling me that if you add the `search` function from any of the top 2 code samples and in your code just change from `var result = _.find(movies, {'title': name});` to `var result = search(movies, name);` it is not working and it gives an exception?

Comment: In your original post you had the collection named as `movies` so I left that. `mvoies` should be the name of the collection which you will be searching against.

Comment: See comment. Search works just fine. Your logic is not correct.