# how convert lodash object (filter object) to the jquery's listview dynamicly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, search

as using answer of this topic for the first step
[how to case insentive contain search with lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308477/how-to-case-insentive-contain-search-with-lodash)

my next step is (my second goal) i use filter to return all the contain matches searched through json file. my goal is to iterate through all matches and convert each lodash object to order list item of jquery listViews with the specific css format.

```
 function search(data, term) {
  return _.filter(data, function(x) { 
return _.includes(_.toLower(x.title), _.toLower(term))}) 
}

document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var name = document.getElementById('input').value;
const data = [{ "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Zane_Ziadi_HQ.mp4", "title": "Zane Ziadi" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/DarBastAzadiHQ.mp4", "title": "Darbast Azadi" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Cheghadr_Vaght_Dari_HQ.mp4", "title": "Cheghadr Vaght Dari" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Mashaal_HQ.mp4", "title": "Mashaal" }, { "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Red_Carpet_HQ.mp4", "title": "Red Carpet" } ]

  var result = search(data, name);  // <-- change to use the new search fn
  if (!result) {
    console.log('Nothing found');
  } else {
    console.log('Go to ' + result.video_url);
  var ind = 0;
         listLength = result.length;
 //FIXME 
          listHTML = $.map(result, function(entry) {
           ind++;
     //FIXME 
           if (ind === 1)  {
                return "<li class=\"itemListClass\" id=\"movieListId\" data-theme=\"b\" style=\"padding-top:25px;padding-left: 15px;line-height:70px\"><a style=\"font-size:1.5em;\" class=\"list\"  href='" + entry.video_url + "'>" + entry.title + "</a></li>";
            }else {
            return "<li class=\"itemListClass\" id=\"movieListId\" style=\"padding-left: 15px;margin-left: 10px;line-height:70px\"><a style=\"font-size:1.5em;\" class=\"list\"  href='" + entry.video_url + "'>" + entry.title + "</a></li>";
            }
           }).join('');
       $("#listUl").append(listHTML).listview("refresh").trigger('create');
  }
});
```

please note the first item in the listview has different stylesheet (has data-theme=\"b\" parameter)
also please note because of hardware limitation i can't use ES6. please use jquery and pure javascript for your answers. you can use .map lodash or any other data types to convert with specific css.

please note my listview filled out dynamically from javascript code

```
  <input id='input' type='text' placeholder="Search term">
  <ol id="listUl" data-role="listview" data-icon="false"  style="margin-right: 5px;">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with an array so you can use lodash `isEmpty` to check if it has any items in it. Also you do not need to use a separate counter to track the index since `jquery` map (and any `map` has the index as its 2nd argument).

You can try something like this:

```
 function search(data, term) {
   return _.filter(data, function(x) {
     return _.includes(_.toLower(x.title), _.toLower(term))
   })
 }

 document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
   var name = document.getElementById('input').value;
   const data = [{
     "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Zane_Ziadi_HQ.mp4",
     "title": "Zane Ziadi"
   }, {
     "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/DarBastAzadiHQ.mp4",
     "title": "Darbast Azadi"
   }, {
     "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Cheghadr_Vaght_Dari_HQ.mp4",
     "title": "Cheghadr Vaght Dari"
   }, {
     "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Mashaal_HQ.mp4",
     "title": "Mashaal"
   }, {
     "video_url": "http://63.237.48.3/ipnx/media/movies/Red_Carpet_HQ.mp4",
     "title": "Red Carpet"
   }]

   var result = search(data, name);
   if (_.isEmpty(result)) {
     console.log('Nothing found');
   } else {
     listHTML = $.map(result, function(entry, i) {
       if (i == 0) {
         return "<li class=\"itemListClass\" id=\"movieListId\" data-theme=\"b\" style=\"padding-top:25px;padding-left: 15px;line-height:70px\"><a style=\"font-size:1.5em;\" class=\"list\"  href='" + entry.video_url + "'>" + entry.title + "</a></li>";
       } else {
         return "<li class=\"itemListClass\" id=\"movieListId\" style=\"padding-left: 15px;margin-left: 10px;line-height:70px\"><a style=\"font-size:1.5em;\" class=\"list\"  href='" + entry.video_url + "'>" + entry.title + "</a></li>";
       }
     }).join('');
     $("#listUl").append(listHTML).listview("refresh").trigger('create');
   }
 });
```

You can see it [working here](http://jsfiddle.net/akrion/9oeztjhf/2/)